# I get "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error " even though I set it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I am having this error even though I have headers assigned in angular's $http service:

```
function Hello($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/races',
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'accept',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.races = response;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

}

This is full error message on console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/races. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63343' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title>Hello AngularJS</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="hello.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="Hello">
<p>The ID is {{races.raceId}}</p>
<p>The name is {{races.raceName}}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the localhost:8080/races I can fully see the json:

```
[{"raceId":8446,"raceName":"test1"},{"raceId":8447,"raceName":"test2"}]
```

Comment: You don't set it in request...it has to be set at server in response. You can't control that with the request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is related with the fact that 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' needs to be set at the server. By doing this you enable CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)

Browsers have a security policy that prevents your javascript code to make requests from services that are not within your domain. For example if your javascript code is executed in http://example.com and the service you are targeting is found at http://example.com/api/myservice then your request will go through normally. If however, the service you are trying to access is at http://someotherdomain.net then the browser will not complete your request successfully even if the server responds normally.

You will have to read documentation about whatever web server software you're using on how to set headers on it. When you set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' on your server your are essentially saying to the world - "You can load my data onto any browser application that lives in any domain". This means anyone in the world can call your service and if you wish to prevent this, you will have to implement authentication (common for this are API key models).

Answer (score 2):

The CORS headers need to be sent by the server.

> The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing standard works by adding new HTTP
>   headers that allow servers to describe the set of origins that are
>   permitted to read that information using a web browser.  Additionally,
>   for HTTP request methods that can cause side-effects on user data (in
>   particular, for HTTP methods other than GET, or for POST usage with
>   certain MIME types), the specification mandates that browsers
>   "preflight" the request, soliciting supported methods from the server
>   with an HTTP OPTIONS request method, and then, upon "approval" from
>   the server, sending the actual request with the actual HTTP request
>   method.  Servers can also notify clients whether "credentials"
>   (including Cookies and HTTP Authentication data) should be sent with
>   requests.

[Read more.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)